# cargo.toml conditional feature on optional dev dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In cargo, it is possible to conditionally activate a feature on a dependency based on the main crate features, using the [`crate/feature` syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html):

```ini
[features]
# Enables parallel processing support by enabling the "rayon" feature of jpeg-decoder.
parallel = ["jpeg-decoder/rayon"]
```

This works if `jpeg-decoder` is in the main `[dependencies]` section of `Cargo.toml`. However, if `jpeg-decoder` is in the `[dev-dependencies]` section, and it is not included at publish time ([because path dev-dependencies are ignored](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies), for instance), then it fails with the following error:

```
error: failed to verify package tarball

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `.../Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `parallel` includes `jpeg-decoder/rayon`, but `jpeg-decoder` is not a dependency
```

Is there a way to work around that ?

Comment: If that dependency doesn't affect the resulting lib, why you want to conditionally enabled/disable some of the features of that dependency? Is that for an acceptance testing of the compatibility with different 3rd parties?

Comment: It is a dev dependency used in tests, and the crate has to be tested with multiple feature combinations.

Comment: I see, that was my guess. I often use a separate module (or project) for acceptance testing, for multiple different reasons, and this one looks like one. Did you consider this?